Sklearm FeatureHasher not working on a single column in a dataframe
I tried performing the feature hasher on a single column in my dataframe but it keeps on giving the error:

ValueError: Samples can not be a single string. The input must be an iterable over iterables of strings.

from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher

hash_vector_size = 50
fh = FeatureHasher(n_features=hash_vector_size, input_type='string')
hashed_df = pd.DataFrame(fh.transform(X_train["Item_Identifier"]).toarray(),
                         columns=['H'+str(i) for i in range (hash_vector_size)])

I was expecting a dataframe of 50 columns where the data would have been hashed in

You were almost there:
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher
import pandas as pd

data = {"Item_Identifier": ["ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5"]}
X_train = pd.DataFrame(data)

hash_vector_size = 50
fh = FeatureHasher(n_features=hash_vector_size, input_type='string')
hashed_features = fh.transform([[item] for item in X_train["Item_Identifier"]])

hashed_df = pd.DataFrame(hashed_features.toarray(),
                         columns=['H'+str(i) for i in range(hash_vector_size)])

print(hashed_df)

which gives
H0   H1   H2   H3   H4   H5   H6   H7   H8   H9  ...  H40  H41  H42  H43  \
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 -1.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   

   H44  H45  H46  H47  H48  H49  
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  

[5 rows x 50 columns]

